# Show only first input error when click on submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on validation task when I click on submit button when form is empty.
I want to show only first input error message. When I enter input in the first input, error message as well as red border should be removed.

HTML:

```
<form class="memberLogin-form" method="post" action="" name="memLogin" id="memLoginForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h6>MEMBER LOGIN</h6>
    <input type='text' name="email" id="email" placeholder="Company email" class="form-control email" />
    <span class="cstError">Enter your email</span><span id="cstEmailError">not a valid email</span>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="psw" id="psw" class="form-control">
    <span class="cstError">Enter your password</span>
    <button type="submit" class="form-control btn">Sign In</button>
    <p>
    </p>
    <a href="cant-login">Can’t login</a>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".succesTxt").hide();
$('#cstEmailError').hide();
$("#memLoginForm").submit(function() {
    var email = $("#email").val()
    var pass = $("#psw").val();
    var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (email == "") {
        $("#email").css("border", "solid 1px red");
        $("#email").next().show().css({
            "color": "red",
            "padding": "10px 0 10px 0",
            "display": "block"
        });
        $('#cstEmailError').hide();
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#email").next().hide();
        $("#email").css("border", "none");
        $('#cstEmailError').hide();
        $(".cstError").hide()
    }

    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= email.length) {
        $('#cstEmailError').show();
        $(".cstError").hide()
        return false;
    } else {
        $('#cstEmailError').hide();
        $(".cstError").hide()
    }
    if (pass == "") {
        $("#psw").css("border", "solid 1px red");
        $(this).find(".cstError").show().css({
            "color": "red",
            "padding": "10px 0 10px 0",
            "display": "block"
        });
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#psw").css("border", "none");
        $(".cstError").hide();
    }
})

})
```

Comment: I can't understand what you mean by `when i enter input in the first input error message as well as red border should be removed`. You enter "input" in the first input error message?? What does that mean? Can you try to ask clear questions please?

Comment: in the first click it should show error message after enter email it should hide

Comment: handle the change event on input, you are really doing very complex coding   use separate css

Answer (score 0):

Use [onkeyup="removevalidation()"] a onkeyup function in email input field to remove the validation message on entering input value.

```js
$(".succesTxt").hide();
$('#cstEmailError').hide();
$("#memLoginForm").submit(function() {
    var email = $("#email").val()
    var pass = $("#psw").val();
    var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (email == "") {
        $("#email").css("border", "solid 1px red");
        $("#email").next().show().css({
            "color": "red",
            "padding": "10px 0 10px 0",
            "display": "block"
        });
        $('#cstEmailError').hide();
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#email").next().hide();
        $("#email").css("border", "none");
        $('#cstEmailError').hide();
        $(".cstError").hide()
    }

    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= email.length) {
        $('#cstEmailError').show();
        $(".cstError").hide()
        return false;
    } else {
        $('#cstEmailError').hide();
        $(".cstError").hide()
    }
    if (pass == "") {
        $("#psw").css("border", "solid 1px red");
        $(this).find(".cstError").show().css({
            "color": "red",
            "padding": "10px 0 10px 0",
            "display": "block"
        });
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#psw").css("border", "none");
        $(".cstError").hide();
    }
})
function removevalidation(){
$('#cstEmailError').hide();
        $(".cstError").hide()
        $("#email").css("border", "solid 1px");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="memberLogin-form" method="post" action="" name="memLogin" id="memLoginForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h6>MEMBER LOGIN</h6>
    <input onkeyup="removevalidation()" type='text' name="email" id="email" placeholder="Company email" class="form-control email" />
    <span class="cstError">Enter your email</span><span id="cstEmailError">not a valid email</span>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="psw" id="psw" class="form-control">
    <span class="cstError">Enter your password</span>
    <button type="submit" class="form-control btn">Sign In</button>
    <p>
    </p>
    <a href="cant-login">Can’t login</a>
</form>
```